# How to parse data with binary elements into a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, parsing, binary

Sample looks like this:

```
lst = ['ms 20 3 -s 10 \n', '17954 11302 58011\n', '\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0706 0.2241 0.2575 0.889 \n', '0001000010\n', '0101000010\n', '0101010010\n', '0001000010\n', '\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0038 0.1622 0.1972 \n', '0110000110\n', '1001001000\n', '0010000110\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0155 0.0779 0.2092 \n', '0000001011\n', '0000001011\n', '0000001011\n']
```

Every new set starts with the $$. I need to parse the data such that, I have the following list of lists.

```
sample = [['0001000010', '0101000010', '0101010010', '0001000010'],['0110000110', '1001001000', '0010000110'],['0000001011', '0000001011', '0000001011'] # Required Output
```

Code attempted

```
sample =[[]]
sample1 = ""
seqlist = []

for line in lst: 
    if line.startswith("$$"):
        if line in '01': #Line contains only 0's or 1
          sample1.append(line) #Append each line that with 1 and 0's in a string one after another
    sample.append(sample1.strip()) #Do this or last line is lost
print sample

Output:[[], '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I am a newbie at parsing data and trying to figure out how to get this right. Suggestions on how to modify the code along with explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in the following way:

```
import re

lst = ['ms 20 3 -s 10 \n', '17954 11302 58011\n', '\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0706 0.2241 0.2575 0.889 \n', '0001000010\n', '0101000010\n', '0101010010\n', '0001000010\n', '\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0038 0.1622 0.1972 \n', '0110000110\n', '1001001000\n', '0010000110\n', '$$\n', 'segsites: 10\n', 'positions: 0.0155 0.0779 0.2092 \n', '0000001011\n', '0000001011\n', '0000001011\n']

result = []
curr_group = []
for item in lst:
    item = item.rstrip() # Remove \n
    if '$$' in item:
        if len(curr_group) > 0: # Check to see if binary numbers have been found.
            result.append(curr_group)
            curr_group = []
    elif re.match('[01]+$', item): # Checks to see if string is binary (0s or 1s).
        curr_group.append(item)

result.append(curr_group) # Appends final group due to lack of ending '$$'. 

print(result)
```

Basically, you want to iterate through the items until you find `'$$'`, then add any binary characters you've found previously to your final result, and start a new group. Every binary string you find (using the regex) should be added to the current group.

Finally, you need to add the last set of binary numbers, since there is no trailing `'$$'`

Comment: I seem to have trouble making it work for my original data set though. https://eval.in/673188

Comment: In my original data set, the separators ($$) are different. Once I change the type of separators, the output collapses.

Comment: Sorry was making dinner - shouldn't you just be able to change the line: `if '$$' in item:` so that it looks for a different type of separator, e.g. if your separator was `'@@'` it would look like: `if '@@' in item:`. Or is your problem more nuanced?

Comment: Thats alright. I did exactly that, but strangely it did not work  eval.in/673188

Comment: Ah just saw your link. Your issue is you assumed the regex pattern `$` was related to your separator. This isn't the case: https://eval.in/673215. Specifically the `$` in a regex pattern means that the preceeding regex commands must meet the end of the string or the regex won't match. This stops a match on strings like `'01010NOTBINARY'`.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working - good luck with whatever script you're writing!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is (at least) here: `if line in '01'`.

This line means `if line == '0' or line == '1'`, which is absolutely not what you want.

A basic but working approach, would be to test, for every string, if it is composed only of `0` and `1`:

```
def is_binary(string) :
    for c in string :
        if c not in '01' :
            return False
    return True
```

This function returns `True` if `string` *can be interpreted as* a binary value, `False` if not.

Of course you have to manage that '\n' at the end, but you got the main idea ;)